# My EditText keeps coming out as null

Tags: android, android-intent

I've been working on this app that collects information, then sends it in email form.  All of my other EditTexts are working with the exception of the very first one, pilot (the hint is name, as in the name of the pilot). I've gone through this thoroughly for multiple hours but I just cant seem to find what is the problem.  The only reason I know its null is because when it goes into the email format all it says is null

```
public class InfoSheet extends AppCompatActivity {
private double VesselUnits;
private EditText pilot, ship, to, from, LOA, MBDTH, CUSD, zone1, zone2, CallSign;
private Spinner agent_spinner;
private Button btnSubmit;
private String date, agent, Spilot, Sship, Sto, Sfrom, Szone1, Szone2, SCallSign, SVesselUnits;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_info_sheet);
    date=getTodaysDate();
    addListenerOnButton();
}
public void collectNCalc(){
    //grab all of our info
    agent_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.agent_spinner);
    btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
    pilot = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Pilot);
    ship = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ship);
    to = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.to);
    from = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.from);
    LOA = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.LOA);
    MBDTH = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.MBDTH);
    CUSD = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CUSD);
    zone1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.zone1);
    zone2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.zone2);
    CallSign = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CallSign);

    //convert what we need to int to do equations
    String sLOA = LOA.getText().toString();
    double intLOA = Integer.valueOf(sLOA);
    intLOA = intLOA*3.281;

    String sMBDTH = MBDTH.getText().toString();
    double intMBDTH = Integer.valueOf(sMBDTH);
    intMBDTH = intMBDTH*3.281;

    String sCUSD = CUSD.getText().toString();
    double intCUSD = Integer.valueOf(sCUSD);
    intCUSD = intCUSD*3.281;

    VesselUnits = intLOA*intMBDTH*intCUSD;
    VesselUnits = VesselUnits/10000;
    Spilot=pilot.getText().toString();
    Sship=ship.getText().toString();
    Sto=to.getText().toString();
    Sfrom=from.getText().toString();
    Szone1=zone1.getText().toString();
    Szone2=zone2.getText().toString();
    SCallSign=CallSign.getText().toString();
    agent=agent_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    //SVesselUnits=String.valueOf(VesselUnits);
}
public void addListenerOnButton() {
    final Context context2 = this;
    btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i2 = new Intent(context2, DigitalSignature.class);
            //do the Calc
            collectNCalc();
            //pass to next activity
            i2.putExtra("Pilot",Spilot);
            i2.putExtra("ship",Sship);
            i2.putExtra("to",Sto);
            i2.putExtra("from",Sfrom);
            i2.putExtra("zone1",Szone1);
            i2.putExtra("zone2",Szone2);
            i2.putExtra("callsign",SCallSign);
            i2.putExtra("agent",agent);
            i2.putExtra("vessleunits",VesselUnits);
            i2.putExtra("date",date);
            startActivity(i2);
        }

    });
}
```

its sent to the next and final activity:

```
public class DigitalSignature extends AppCompatActivity {
String pilot, ship, to, from, zone1, zone2, CallSign, agent, date;
Toolbar toolbar;
Button btn_get_sign, mClear, mGetSign, mCancel, btn_send;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_digital_signature);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        pilot = extras.getString("pilot");
        ship = extras.getString("ship");
        to = extras.getString("to");
        from = extras.getString("from");
        zone1 = extras.getString("zone1");
        zone2 = extras.getString("zone2");
        CallSign = extras.getString("callsign");
        agent = extras.getString("agent");
        vesselUnit = extras.getDouble("vesselunits");
        date = extras.getString("date");
    }
btn_send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v){
            Uri path = Uri.parse("file://" + file);
            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, pilot+"\n"+ship+"\n"+to+"\n"+from+"\n"+zone1+"\n"+zone2+"\n"+CallSign+"\n"+agent+"\n"+vesselUnit);
            // set the type to 'email'
            emailIntent.setType("image/png");
            String to[] = {"metropilottickets@gmail.com"};
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
            // the attachment
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);
            // the mail subject
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, pilot+"'s Ticket for "+ship);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent , "Send email..."));
        }
    });
}
```

I left out a lot of the other code that's irrelevant to my question, but if anyone can point out why I'm getting null you'd be a life saver!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `extras.getString("Pilot");`

insteadof `extras.getString("pilot");`